# Regex to get words within a Backslash

Tags: regex, expression

Following is my string:
`F:\Shared\Common\1a\gruwr050.pdf`

How do I get the strings preceding the 3rd Backslash using Regex?

For example: `F:\Shared\Common`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^(?:[^\\]*\\){2}[^\\]*` as pattern.

Here's Python example:

```py
>>> re.findall(r'^(?:[^\\]*\\){2}[^\\]*', r'F:\Shared\Common\1a\gruwr050.pdf')
['F:\\Shared\\Common']
```

Javascript example:

```js
'F:\\Shared\\Common\\1a\\gruwr050.pdf'.match(/^(?:[^\\]*\\){2}[^\\]*/)
// => ["F:\Shared\Common"]
```